# Which Android device / os support BLE peripheral mode

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to develop a BLE peripheral advertising app on Android, but the following call:

```
bluetoothAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()
```

always returns false.

Where can I find a list of devices supporting it? Is it feasible, as of today, to develop such a peripheral or should I avoid this because only a minimal set of devices support it?

Any help/suggestion is welcome

Comment: My device is SM-G388F with Android 5.1.1

Comment: did you read the bluetooth le documentation? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: @tyczj sure I did. Did I miss some info there, about peripheral devices support?